# Ad Mob crashes when returning to Fragment Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, admob

I am fairly new to Android programming, and I have created an app with many Fragments. I've followed Google's instructions on how to set up the Google Ad Mobs. I've got this working for the very first time when you click on a particular fragment. However, if I return to that fragment, the app crashes and doesn't hit the `Ad Fragment` class...

My Java class:

```
public class ContactsListFragment extends BaseFragment {
ArrayList<Contact> allContacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

...


public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ad, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

public static class AdFragment extends Fragment {

    private AdView mAdView;

    public AdFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onActivityCreated(bundle);

        // Gets the ad view defined in layout/ad_fragment.xml with ad unit ID set in
        // values/strings.xml.
        mAdView = (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);

        // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device. e.g.
        // "Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") to get test ads on this device."
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ad, container, false);
    }

    /** Called when leaving the activity */
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    /** Called when returning to the activity */
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.resume();
        }
    }

    /** Called before the activity is destroyed */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

And my xml file for this class:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/adFragment"
    android:name="com.oozzat.app.ContactsListFragment$AdFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

My Logcat looks like this:

`12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #80: Error inflating class fragment
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409):    at com.oozzat.app.ContactsListFragment.onCreateView(ContactsListFragment.java:52)
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #80: Duplicate id 0xffffffff, tag adFragmentPlaceholder, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.oozzat.app.ContactsListFragment$PlaceholderFragment
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4971)
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)`

Comment: post the stacktrace of your crash

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
12-19 09:35:13.474: E/AndroidRuntime(22409): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #80: Duplicate id 0xffffffff, tag adFragmentPlaceholder, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.oozzat.app.ContactsListFragment$PlaceholderFragment
```

Essentially you are using the same resource id multiple times within the same View hierarchy.

Look in the layout XML for your Activity and the Fragments you are loading. Look for a duplicate id.